# Why this constexpr expression gives me an error?

Tags: c++

In the code below, `constexpr` for the line 2 does not give an error, but line 1 does.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ComplexNum{
public:constexpr ComplexNum(int _r=0,int _i=0):r(_r),i(_i){}
private:
     int r,i;

};

int randGen(){
return 10;
}
constexpr int numGen(int  i,int j){
return i+j;
}
int main()
{
    
    constexpr int i=10,j=20;
    constexpr ComplexNum c3(randGen(),randGen());    //line 1
    constexpr ComplexNum c4(numGen(i,j),numGen(i,j));//line 2

   
    return 0;
}
```

From the knowledge I have, `constexpr` evaluates the expression at compile time.

Then, shouldn't the compiler be able to evaluate the expression in line 1, because it returns a constant integer (10 in this case)?. If not, how will line 2 be okay?

Comment: `randGen` needs to be declared `constexpr`, yes?

Comment: Yes or consteval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't compile line one because `randGen()` is not `constexpr`. The compiler can't magically tell if a function is constexpr. Maybe it looks constexpr, but you actually want it to run at runtime. For that reason, the compiler doesn't evaluate expressions which are not marked constexpr explicitly. Do this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ComplexNum{
public:constexpr ComplexNum(int _r=0,int _i=0):r(_r),i(_i){}
private:
     int r,i;

};

constexpr int randGen(){
return 10;
}
constexpr int numGen(int  i,int j){
return i+j;
}
int main()
{
    
    constexpr int i=10,j=20;
    constexpr ComplexNum c3(randGen(),randGen());    //line 1
    constexpr ComplexNum c4(numGen(i,j),numGen(i,j));//line 2

   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Maybe it looks constexpr, but you actually want it to run at runtime". It's always possible for a `constexpr` function to be evaluated at runtime if its arguments aren't known until runtime, and it's possible for a non-`constexpr` function to get evaluated at compile time if the compiler is able to do so. But your answer's overall point that whether the return value of `randGen` can be used in a constant expression must be determined by the signature of `randGen`, not the body of `randGen`, is correct.